# dataframe merge/join on rows with partial index overlap

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have the following 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2'],
   ...:                     'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2'],
   ...:                     'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2'],
   ...:                     'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2']},
   ...:                     index=[0, 1, 2])
```

and

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'E': ['E2', 'E3', 'E4'],
   ...:             'F': ['F2', 'F3', 'F4']},
   ...:                 index=[2, 3, 4])
```

As you can see df1 and df2 only have index 2 as an overlap.

I want to combine these 2 df's in such a way that the end result is:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2',np.nan,np.nan],
   ...:                     'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2',np.nan,np.nan],
   ...:                     'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2',np.nan, np.nan],
   ...:                     'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2',np.nan,np.nan],
                            'E': [np.nan, np.nan, 'E2','E3','E4'],
                            'F': [np.nan, np.nan, 'F2','F3','F4']},
   ...:                     index=[0, 1, 2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df1.combine_first(df2)
Out: 
     A    B    C    D    E    F
0   A0   B0   C0   D0  NaN  NaN
1   A1   B1   C1   D1  NaN  NaN
2   A2   B2   C2   D2   E2   F2
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   E3   F3
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   E4   F4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use concat, axis 1

```
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)

    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   A0  B0  C0  D0  NaN NaN
1   A1  B1  C1  D1  NaN NaN
2   A2  B2  C2  D2  E2  F2
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN E3  F3
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN E4  F4
```